# All rows within a given column must match, for all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame of data in which all rows within a given column must match:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   'B': [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'C': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                   'D': [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
                   'E': [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]})

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  1  2  3  4  5
...
6  1  2  3  4  5
7  1  2  3  4  5
8  1  2  3  4  5
9  1  2  3  4  5
```

I would like a quick way to know if there is an variance anywhere in the DataFrame.  At this point, I don't need to know which values have varied, since I will be going in to handle those later.  I just need a quick way to know if the DataFrame needs further attention or if I can ignore it and move on to the next one.

I can check any given column using

```
(df.loc[:,'A'] != df.loc[0,'A']).any()
```

but my Pandas knowledge limits me to iterating through the columns (I understand iteration is frowned upon in Pandas) to compare all of them:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  2  9  4  5
2  1  2  3  4  5
...
6  1  2  3  4  5
7  1  2  3  4  5
8  1  2  3  4  5
9  1  2  3  4  5

for col in df.columns:
    if (df.loc[:,col] != df.loc[0,col]).any():
        print("Found a fail in col %s" % col)
        break

Out: Found a fail in col C
```

Is there an elegant way to return a boolean if any row within any column of a dataframe does not match all the values in the column... possibly without iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   'B': [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'C': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                   'D': [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
                   'E': [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]})
```

You can use the following:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.nunique) > 1
```

Which gives you:

```
A    False
B    False
C    False
D    False
E    False
dtype: bool
```

If we then force a couple of errors:

```
df.loc[3, 'C'] = 0
df.loc[5, 'B'] = 20
```

You then get:

```
A    False
B     True
C     True
D    False
E    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: All the approaches so far would work well, but I think using nunique() will be a good hint to the code reader (me) to what is being done.

Answer (score 4):

You can compare the entire DataFrame to the first row like this:

```
In [11]: df.eq(df.iloc[0], axis='columns')
Out[11]: 
      A     B     C     D     E
0  True  True  True  True  True
1  True  True  True  True  True
2  True  True  True  True  True
3  True  True  True  True  True
4  True  True  True  True  True
5  True  True  True  True  True
6  True  True  True  True  True
7  True  True  True  True  True
8  True  True  True  True  True
9  True  True  True  True  True
```

then test if all values are true:

```
In [13]: df.eq(df.iloc[0], axis='columns').all()
Out[13]: 
A    True
B    True
C    True
D    True
E    True
dtype: bool

In [14]: df.eq(df.iloc[0], axis='columns').all().all()
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: Good idea.  I hadn't thought to look at the problem in that direction.  You've got a great skill with Pandas.   May I ask how long you've been using Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` to loop through columns and check if all the elements in the column are the same:

```
df.apply(lambda col: (col != col[0]).any())

# A    False
# B    False
# C    False
# D    False
# E    False
# dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out apply().  Looks like I need to add that one to my tool bag.